# How to write correctly PyQT5 event function

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

How can I correctly write the event function to pass from one QLineEdit to another one by pressing the enter key?

I know how to do that in this way:

**Working Example**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent

class working(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.show()

        self.x = QLineEdit(self)
        self.x1 = QLineEdit(self)

        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow("x:", self.x)
        layout.addRow("x1:", self.x1)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                self.focusNextPrevChild(True)
        return super().event(event)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = working()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now i want to understand how to do the same with this code (i think that the problem is with super() and **init** but i don't know why).

**UNWorking Basic Example**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(193, 119)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
 
        self.x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.x)
        self.x1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.x1)
 
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
 
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                self.focusNextPrevChild(True)
        return super().event(event)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that with "that" code? Is it because you want to build your application with Designer instead of manually create the whole interface?

Comment: for study mainly and in the second logic i can do MainWindow.Close() without close the whole app. I'm a beginner and i don't understand correctly how to use __init__ super() and parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example does not work because you're trying to override the `event` method, which is a method available only for QWidget subclasses, while your `Ui_MainWindow` is a simple python `object` subclass, so it will never be called.

The `event()` method is called by Qt on any QWidget, and since you are overriding it in the first example, your method is actually called. In the second example you're not overriding the QWidget `event`, but you're just creating a function that is never called by anything.

Theoretically you *could* overwrite the `event` method of the `MainWindow` object in `setupUi` (that's what's called "monkey patching"):

```
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...
        MainWindow.event = self.event
```

But that won't work as the `self` you're referring to in that function is actually the `Ui_MainWindow` instance, not the actual QMainWindow instance. While you *could* use a lambda, and add the argument with the MainWindow instance, I'd strongly advise against that, and the following explanation will clarify why you shouldn't do it.

There's no point in doing what you're trying to achieve, for a simple reason: modifying or trying to mimic the behavior of `pyuic` generated files is something that should **NEVER** be done.

Editing is discouraged mostly because whenever you need to change something in the UI from Designer, you'll end up trying to integrate the new generated code (hoping that you've not overwritten the file in the meantime) with the existing one, which will normally result in tons of errors, issues, crashes and headaches.

Editing or mimicking is discouraged as it makes very hard to implement simple class operations or override existing methods. Also, while I can understand you're interest in studying how it works, except for reading how the interface is created within the `setupUi`, there's nothing more to learn there. The pyuic files are intended only as an "utility layer" to ease up programming in PyQt, they should *always* only be imported and used as suggested in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

If you want to implement the event of the first example, you'll need to use your own subclass and use one of the approaches suggested in the link above. The most common and easy to use is the multiple inheritance approach:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class Working(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                self.focusNextPrevChild(True)
        return super().event(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Working()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: I'm assuming that you've generated the file *again* with `pyuic` and that is named `ui_mainwindow.py`; also, note that if you're using a QMainWindow in designer, you must subclass from the same class (QMainWindow, not QWidget); finally, since you're already subclassing from QMainWindow *and* Ui_MainWindow, you have to create an instance of `Working`, not one of QMainWindow, nor one of Ui_MainWindow.

Another possibility is to use the `uic` module, which allows to import the `.ui` file directly without the need to rebuild the whole interface everytime.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Working(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('mainWindow.ui', self)
        # ...
```

Comment: I'm putting a new example in pastebin

Comment: @yalodek (please write in english) What does not work? Have you checked the letter casing? If `Ui_MainWindow` is in the same file, then you should not import it (but you should *not* place that class in the script, as explained the pyuic file should always be imported).

Comment: See my edit. You should just create an instance of `Working`, not QMainWindow and Working.

Comment: Now it work well, i didn't see that now i need to call it with mainWindow. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that if my answer solves your issue as expected you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on its left.

Comment: I just noticed that mainWindow.close() closes the whole app. I'm back to square one

Comment: Do you know how i can close only the UI as i said before?

Comment: @yalodek see the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) property, but use it with care.

Comment: That’s the reason for which i wanted use the “unworking basic example” that designer gave me. Don’t u think MainWindow.close() is a pythonic way? The method close() kill entire app without close chromedriver(in my case)

Comment: Despite the fact that the "unworking" example should not be used for the reasons explained above, it wouldn't change anything, as it's independent from the QApplication instance. I don't know what you're referring about chromedriver (but that's not the scope of this question), but if you don't want to close the app when the last window is closed just set the property above; that's how Qt works (and for good reasons), it gives you the alternative and it works fine, and I don't see any "non-pythonic" in that. What would you expect instead?